# Import best practices for python packages

Tags: python

I am trying to better understand python imports when writing a python package. I come from the R world and when writing an R package which depends on functionality from another R package, we only import that functionality. For example

`@importFrom stats qnorm`

Sometimes if you are loading a lot of functionality from a package, it is better to import the whole package

`@import ggplot2`

So my question is, is it better practice to load individual functionality

`from seaborn import set, set_context`

Or to import whole libraries

`import seaborn as sns`

I feel that this is different from importing modules into your environment as I am planning on shipping a package and don't want to have namespace clashes.

Comment: All `import` does is *bind a name* (the loading of the module is done once the first time, loading the whole module). Bind the names you need to make your code workable.

Comment: In general it is considered best practise to use `import ...` or `import ... as ...` precisely to prevent namespace clashes. If you are building a package yourself, **only** import objects that you plan to export in your `__init__.py`.

Comment: Also see ['import module' vs. 'from module import function'](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/187403)

Comment: Thanks all, I think I understand much better now.